# Null-forgiving operator (!) not working in C# >= 8.0

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I tried using this null-forgiving operator (!) in Unity 2020.3.1f1 with vscode. None of these tools have seen this syntax work so I reproduced it into these two fiddles inspired from the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

Same code for both:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    #nullable enable
    public struct Person {
        public string name;
    }
    
    static Person? GetPerson(bool yes) {
        Person ret = new Person();
        ret.name = "coucou";
        if(yes) return ret;
        else return null;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person? person = GetPerson(true);
        if(person != null) Console.WriteLine("name: " + person!.name);
    }
}
```

First with C# 7.3 not workling as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HMS35M

Second with C# 8.0 at least just ignoring the syntax it seems: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mhbqhk

Any idea to make this second one work?

Comment: It's working. Post your code *in the question itself*

Comment: @HansKilian First is obvious via the message, second is 8 or 9 following that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The null-forgiving operator does not apply to `Nullable<T>` - the only available relevant members remain `.Value`, `.HasValue` and `.GetValueOrDefault()`; you would have to use the slightly longer `person.Value.name` / `person.GetValueOrDefault().name`, or you could capture the value during the `if` test:

```cs
if (person is Person val) Console.WriteLine("name: " + val.name);
```

Comment: thanks for learning this new syntax, one line saved for the cast!

Answer (score 4):

The null-forgiving operator(Damn it) operator allows you to notify the compiler that it should ignore a possibly null reference, because you have more information than the compiler does.

> First with C# 7.3 not workling as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HMS35M

The `null-forgiving operator` wasn't implemented till C# 8.0, you would need a nuget package or some alternative work-around to enable the bang symbol's use in this context for C#7.3.

> Any idea to make this second one work?

When using a `Nullable<T>` `struct` you can use the `.Value` property to get the object's value(the actual `Person` `struct` you defined). Without the `.Value` method the compiler doesn't know if you're trying to access the `Nullable<T>` object or the `struct` object you defined. So it can't find the `.name` field on the `Nullable<T>` object.

This should work for you

```cs
if (person != null) Console.WriteLine("name: " + person!.Value.name);
```